# Como activar SSL en Kubernete POD AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dotnetcore

Hola como activar SSL o que la ruta a mi microservicio tenga HTTPS en la URL, he intentado con `CERT-MANAGER` pero nada, o como modificari mi archivo `deployment.yml`

```yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: ms-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ms-app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ms-app-deployment
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: ms-app-deployment
          secret:
            secretName: tls-secret
      containers:
        - name: ms-app
          image: qa.azurecr.io/ms-app:1.00
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "0.5"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: VERSION
              value: "1.00"
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              value: ""
            - name: TOKEN_EXPIRATION
              value: "60"
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ms-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: ms-app-deployment
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```